# How can I find the lowest number in a range, and increase that number by 1 in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

To preface this, I have no background in programming, but I've been working on creating an Initiative tracker for Dungeons and Dragons 5e in Google sheets.

What I would like to do is have a macro that does this for me: When I activate it, it will search the Range (Column C in this case), find the cell with the lowest numerical value, and add 1 to it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

This task can be broken down into two different subtasks:

1. You need to interact with the spreadsheet file to get the values of **column C**. The following code gets from **Sheet1** the values of column **C** starting from the second row until the last row with content:

   ```
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
   const cVals = sh.getRange('C2:C'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat(1);
   ```

`cVals` is a list of all C values in **Sheet1**. In order to find the entry with the minimum value you take advantage of the [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method:

```
const indexMin = cVals.reduce((min_i, x, i, ar) => x < ar[min_i] ? i : min_i, 0);
```

This gives the position of the element in `indexMin` that has the lowest value, starting from `0`. However, `cVals` has a list of C values starting from `C2`. This is why we add `2` in order to find the `row number` in the sheet where column C has the lowest value and then we add `1` to the old value:

```
sh.getRange(indexMin+2,3).setValue(sh.getRange(indexMin+2,3).getValue()+1)
```

2. Finally, you want to be able to execute this function from your spreadsheet file. In order to achieve that, you can create a **custom menu** (macro) using the following code:

   ```
   function onOpen() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Macros')
      .addItem('Add one to C minimum', 'plusOne')
      .addToUi();
   }
   ```

---

### Complete Solution:

```
  function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Macros')
    .addItem('Add one to C minimum', 'plusOne')
    .addToUi();
  }

  function plusOne() {
  
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    const last_row = sh.getLastRow();
    const num_rows = sh.getRange('C:C').getValues().filter(String).length;
    const num_blank = last_row-num_rows;
      
    const cVals = sh.getRange('C2:C'+last_row).getValues().flat(1);
    const indexMin = cVals.reduce((min_i, x, i, ar) => x < ar[min_i] ? i : min_i, 0);
 sh.getRange(indexMin+2+num_blank,3).setValue(sh.getRange(indexMin+2+num_blank,3).getValue()+1)
}
```

---

### Results/Instructions:

1. Click on **Tools** => **Script editor**.
2. Copy/Paste the full code to an empty script.
3. Refresh the spreadsheet and a new macro will be created as a sidebar.
4. Then you can click on it to execute the task.

[image: results]

---

### Assumptions:

1. Column C has a header.
2. The name of the sheet is **Sheet1**. You can adjust this from the code.
3. If there are two minimums (the lowest value appears twice), then it will increment by 1 only the cell that belongs to the **upper row**.

---

### References:

Google Apps Script:

- [official documentation](https://www.google.com/script/start/)

JavaScript libraries:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: This is great, but is there any way to have it add only to cells that have a number in them already? the issue that i'm running into is that it just adds 1 to the empty cells below list that i'm trying to change.

Comment: @AndrewPingry please see my updated solution. Now if there are blank cells in between   the data, it will still work correctly.